# Bottom navigation view with navigation component does not work as expected. Android

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have 3 top-destination fragments (let's say fragments A, B, C). I can navigate between tabs as expected. However, when i navigate to another fragment from top-destination fragment (fragment A -> fragment A1), I encounter  next issue:

When i navigate to another top-destination fragment through bottom nav view, and navigate back (fragment A1 -> fragment B -> fragment A). App opens fragment A1 instead of fragment A and tab B is highlighted as active. Clicking on tab A do nothing.

What is the issue? Here is my setup.

Top-destination fragments are: profile, tools_library, settings

MainActivity.kt

```
val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_profile, R.id.navigation_tools_library,
            R.id.navigation_settings
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(
        navController)
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.BottomNavigationView"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_profile">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:name="com.example.pocketpsy.presentation.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="@string/profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_tools_library"
    android:name="com.example.pocketpsy.presentation.toolslibrary.ToolsLibraryFragment"
    android:label="@string/tool"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tools_library">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_description"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_description" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_tool"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_tool" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_description"
    android:name="com.example.pocketpsy.presentation.description.DescriptionFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="toolID"
        app:argType="string" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_tool"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_tool"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_tools_library" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_tool"
    android:name="com.example.pocketpsy.presentation.tool.ToolFragment"
    android:label="@string/tool"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tool">
    <argument
        android:name="toolID"
        app:argType="string" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_results"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_results" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_results"
    android:name="com.example.pocketpsy.presentation.results.ResultsFragment"
    android:label="@string/results">
    <argument
        android:name="toolID"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="resultsID"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
    android:name="com.example.pocketpsy.presentation.settings.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="fragment_settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
```

How i navigate from tools_library fragment to description fragment or tool fragment:

```
val action: NavDirections
if (toolViewModel.toolDataMap.value!!.isEmpty()) {
action = ToolsLibraryFragmentDirections.navigateToDescription(toolID)
findNavController().navigate(action)
} else {
action = ToolsLibraryFragmentDirections.navigateToTool(toolID)
findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

Comment: I guess you're asking the same question as mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260709/android-bottomnavigationview-tab-indicator-not-consistent-with-mutiple-back-stac.

Comment: @SamChen THANK YOU! I thought this is a dead end, couldn't find any information on this issue, you saved my day